# Go:calculation on UUID

Tags: go

I really appreciate some help regarding the below mentioned issue:

I am trying to generate UUID as follow:
[image]

now I need to call checksum method as:
[image]

The problem is as this checksum method accepts byte array. but UUID returned by getUUID method is uuis.UUID? Also, it has hyphens. How can I deal with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do not use screenshots, paste the actual code please.

Answer (score 1):

Most UUID packages use a byte array to represent a UUID.  Assuming that's what your package does, use a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) to convert the array to a slice:

```
uuid := getUUID()
sum := calChecksum(uuid[:])
```

Use this simpler code if the package uses a slice instead of an array:

```
sum := calChecksum(getUUID())
```

Both snippets work with slices.

Recommended reading: [Go Tour starting at arrays](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6).

Comment: Thanks, And how can we remove hyphens from uuid ?

Comment: @Anvy hyphens are not part of the UUID, only a conventional part of its representation as a string. As for how to remove characters from a string in Go, a quick search will yield many results.